# Bind label in ControlTemplate to Window title

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0, controltemplate

For a new application I created a custom ControlTemplate for a window so that all windows have the same look and feel. As I set the property `WindowStyle` to `none` and `AllowsTransparency` to `true`, I needed to create my own window controls (like close button, title bar etc.).

Is there any possibility to bind the text of a label, which is contained in the ControlTemplate, to the Window title of this one window just by using the xaml code in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{TemplateBinding Title}` should do it ([`TemplateBinding` reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx)).